# When do we use the article "a" before "people"?

Tags: articles

I read a sentence in a chapter named "The Last Lesson" which was:

That, we must guard it among us and never forget it, because when a people are enslaved, as long as they hold fast to their language, it is as if they had the key to their
prison.

I ponder over why the article "a" has been used before "people" which is a plural noun.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/605125/2085).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A people***

(plural ***PEOPLES***)

-
"body of persons that are united by a common culture, tradition, or sense of kinship, that typically have common language, institutions, and beliefs, and that often constitute a politically organized group"

([Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/people) )

Compare two examples from Reverso.context.net:

"Spain was trying to make the Gibraltarians renounce their demand to be recognized as ***a people.***"

"Some Governments and their ***peoples*** remain wary of this enterprise."